CiviCRM upgrade - interesting feature
I have noticed a feature that sometimes happens when applying an upgrade. The user for our database has "!" as part of the password , when I applied the 5.71.2 upgrade today that password string has been replaced with %21 instead of the "!".
It happened on a previous upgrade as well but 5.71.1 didn't generate the issue.
It's a slight inconvenience but as soon as I get the "A critical error etc." message on database upgrade I know exactly what has happened and go into civicrm.settings.php and replace the special characters with the "!" and it springs into life.
